# i am looking to a max value from list of string with special characters. getting the expectedd behaviour can some one help out?

Tags: java, list

Here is my code:

```
public class MaxValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // call the getMaxValue from the list
        // expected value is 13
        System.out.println(getMaxValue(Arrays.asList("<12.5", "5", "10", "-1", "12.5", "13")));}    

       //get max value 13 and am expecting the output to be 13  

    }
```

// I am unable to get the particular behavior can someone please help me out

```
    public static String getMaxValue(List<String> values){
        String result = null;
        for (String value : values) {
            //logic
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it yourself first.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Avoid making long titles. Describe the problem, input and expected output appropriately.

Comment: @dryleaf input is Arrays.asList("<12.5", "5", "10", "-1"))  output value is String and value expected is <12.5.

Comment: would you please explain what does the "<" character mean? and what are the valid characters?

Comment: @hamid ghasemi that means value can be less than 12.5  and value can be -1 . I can say the max is <12.5 since the value can be 12.49

Comment: What are the valid inputs? Strings or integers or both strings and integers? and why? Also give a clear example of `input` -> `output` with explanation.

Comment: @dryleaf the value is stored in database as string. its stored database as <11 , 10, -1 , 2.0, 5.99 so if i want to show the user the max value for that data type i need to show him the value has <11. I have read access to table so in my logic i need to show the max value has <11 on the screen

Comment: @guy If you can help me out. I have already tried and am not getting the expected behavior

Comment: Why are you using input `<` in your input (`<11 , 10, -1 , 2.0, 5.99`)?

Comment: @dryleaf that's how the value is stored in database. I don't know why you are not getting the question.

Comment: @shekar Than post what you have tried and what was the output. Currently it looks like you want us to do it for you.

Comment: @Guy it seems like you don't know how to solve it. I know what i have tried.

Comment: what are the valid special characters ? "<" and "<=" ? or anything else exist ?

Comment: @Hamidghasemi possibility of values are "<" , "-" .

Comment: @shekar You might know what you have tried, but if you won't show you really tried it yourself no one here will help you. Go over [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have a nice day.

Comment: @Guy public static String getMaxValue(List<String> values){
  double max = 0.0;
  for (String value : values) {
   //logic
   value = value.replaceAll("[^\\d-.]", "");
   double curent = Double.parseDouble(value);
   if(curent > max){
    max = curent;
   }
   
  }
  return String.valueOf(max);
 }

Comment: with this code i get the value has 12.5 but i want to see the output has <12.5

Comment: @Guy if i use the < character in replaceAll function i get some times number format exception or patternsyntaxexception

Comment: @Guy can you help out?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getMaxValue(Arrays.asList("<12.5", "5", "10", "-1")));
    }

    private static String getMaxValue(List<String> strings) {
        List<INumber> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        for(String a : strings){
            numbers.add(new INumber(a));
        }
        Collections.sort(numbers);
        return numbers.get(0).getExactString();
    }

}

class INumber implements Comparable<INumber>{

    private String exactString;
    private float removedSpecials;

    INumber(String exactString){
        this.exactString = exactString;
        removedSpecials = Float.parseFloat(exactString.replace("<", ""));
    }

    public String getExactString(){
        return exactString;
    }

    public boolean hasSpecialChar(){
        return exactString.contains("<");
    }

    public float getExactNumber(){
        return removedSpecials;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NotNull INumber iNumber) {
        if(iNumber.getExactNumber() > getExactNumber())
            return 0;
        else if(iNumber.getExactNumber() == getExactNumber()
              && !iNumber.hasSpecialChar() && hasSpecialChar() )
            return 0; 
        else
            return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution I really appreciate your help. I just want to know how did you got the idea to solve this solution just eager to know the approach. Since i am working java6 code I can't use NotNull annotation instead i have to use iNumber != null Is it right in if condition

Comment: its not working for expected behaviour. If the value is ("<12.5", "5", "10", "-1", "12.5", "13") then the value should be 13 since the max value in list is 13

Comment: @PatrickParker can you tell me where do i need to change code so that i can implement. If possible can you explain at which line i need to change

Comment: @shekar Educate yourself. Search for "JAVA How to parse double" and "JAVA How to implement Comparable." Try, try, try. When you get stuck on a specific problem then open a specific question. This question is too broad. That is why it was closed!

Comment: @PatrickParker I don't understand what you mean. exactNumber is float and I'm comparing two floats.

Comment: @hamidghasemi I think this should be using Float.compareTo. Testing equal (0) is a possibility, which should followed by a special characters check. Special characters "<" means less than, so <12 should test less than 12. Furthermore, why use floats instead of doubles? Might as well take the better precision.

Comment: @PatrickParker I had forgotten to check if a number has special character. thanks. about the doubles, I just assumed float is enough, he can change it to double if he want :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is Java, I advise you to go with an Object-Oriented approach.

First, you need to create a class representing a NumberLinePosition, which will implement the Comparable interface.

```
public class NumberLinePosition implements Comparable<NumberLinePosition> {
    public NumberLinePosition(String toParse) {
```

The members will be an `double` (to hold the numeric portion of the String, and another variable to hold the positional modifier. For modifier, I would recommend using an `enum` (LESS_THAN, NO_MOD, GREATER_THAN).

You will then need to write a compareTo method that first compares doublePart then compares modifier.

```
int compareTo( NumberLinePosition a ) {
```

Once you have completed this, it will be a simple matter to keep a list of NumberLinePositions and sort them using `Collections.sort(myList);`

Comment: thanks for your comment I am new to java. It is too difficult for me to understand.

Comment: I don't have teaching assistant. I am working on my own for project.So currently I am facing this challenge to solve

Comment: @shekar then you should search for related tutorials on these concepts. Or consult your teacher. StackOverflow is not suitable for extended tutoring conversations.

Comment: can you please reply to hamid code please. I am unable to get the result 13 if the list contains the max is 13